# Java password checking, code modification

Tags: java

- Password should consist of minimum 8 characters.
- Password should consist both numbers and letter.
- No special characters are allowed.

The output of this code is always "Invalid Password"
What should be modified to get the correct output?

```
import java.util.*;  
import java.lang.String;  
import java.lang.Character;

public class password {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.print("Please enter a Password: ");  
        String password = input.next();  
        if (isValid(password)) {  
            System.out.println("Valid Password");  
        } else {  
            System.out.println("Invalid Password");  
        }  
    }

    public static boolean isValid(String password) {
        if (password.length() < 8) {
            return false;
        } else {
            for(int i = 0; i <= password.length() - 1; i++) {
                char c = password.charAt(i);
                if (!Character.isLetter(c) | !Character.isDigit(c)) {
                   return false;
                }
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Go through the code in a debugger line by line. Think about the logic. Check what the functions you call return. You'll find it.

Comment: Answer: your program should be modified for the correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

| is a bitwise or, || is a logical or. You should know the difference.

Work this way though:

```
if(!Character.isLetter(c) && !Character.isDigit(c))
           return false;
```

=> If the character is not a letter nor a digit return false

Comment: If I do that it displays Valid password even if it's only letters and even it's only numbers.

Comment: Ah you need a combination of both?

Answer (score 0):

You have only one `|` in your code when doing the OR in your if statement. It should be `||` . I was stumped on the same thing for an hour yesterday :l

Comment: This won't fix the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a bitwise  operator, `||` is a logical operator. Also, there is a problem with the logic. A `Character` can't be a *Letter* and *Digit* at the same time, so this condition is always `true`. Try using `&&`

```
if(!Character.isLetter(c) && !Character.isDigit(c))
    return false;
```

Comment: This won't fix the actual problem

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen just overlooked that. Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

I feel that I should mention a few mistakes in your approach, as it might help save you time in the future.

If your method `isValid`, you have a loop which iterates over all the characters in the string. This is the right way to do this, so you clearly know what you need to do to achive the aim.

However, logically, what this method does next is as follows.

1. Get the first character in the string
2. Check if the character is a digit or a char
3. If that character is not a digit or char, return false

Your method will fall over if the first character is not a char, or not a digit. Rationally, you have the right idea, but a letter is not a number, and vise versa.

Suppose the first letter is 'A' - it's not a number, so return false.
If the first character is '1' - it's not a letter, so return false.

As you have seen, changing the operator to && will stop the program failing if you enter only numbers or letters, but will return false if you add any non alphanumeric value.

If you need to enforce at least one digit and at least one number, you have to store the number of digits and chars you have in the string as you iterate over it.

Have two variables, one to store the total number of digits, and one to store the number of chars, and increment them as you step through the string.

If the total number of digits found is greater than zero, and the total number of letters found is greater than zero, your password is valid.

```
import java.util.*;  
import java.lang.String;  
import java.lang.Character;


public class password {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.print("Please enter a Password: ");  
        String password = input.next();  
        if (isValid(password)) {  
            System.out.println("Valid Password");  
        } else {  
            System.out.println("Invalid Password");  
        }  
    }

public static boolean isValid(String password) {
    if(password.length()<8) {    
       return false;
    } else {
       int dCount = 0;
       int cCount = 0;
       for (int i=0; i<=password.length()-1; i++) {
           char c=password.charAt(i);

           if(Character.isLetter(c) {
               cCount++;
           }
           if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
               dCount++;
           }
       }
       return dCount > 0 && cCount > 0;
   }    
}
```